# How to write shell script on VMDK to derive configuration

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, vmware, virtualization

I have several VMDK files and I would like to write a shell scripts to derive configuration (i.e. No. of CPUs, RAM, NIC, HDDs Size, No of HDDs, etc.).

How can I do this, or where do I start?

Comment: What is your environment? VMPlayer, Workstation, vSphere?

Comment: I am using CentOS 7, having many VMDK from Vmware Vshpere 4, 5.1 and 5.5

Comment: The VMDK files are binary files, some information (e.g. disc layout) is written in there as text, but for other things you need to use a program that understands the VMDK format and outputs what you want as text (preferably in the form `key=value` so you can source the output).

Comment: Can you suggest some application which I can use on EL6 or EL7 to just open this VMDK files to check their hardware configuration. Is it possible to just install Vshpere on EL6 or EL7? Just to open this VMDK files and to check configuration.

Comment: Files ending with `.vmdk` are disk images. If what you are after is the virtual machine description instead, you should be looking at files ending with `.vmx`. See [this](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_learning_files_in_a_vm.html).

Comment: How is this related to kvm?

Comment: Hello Dyasny! I have just asked about `VMDK`, `KVM` is not involved over here. My Operating System is Linux (i.e. CentOS 6.5 and CentOS 7). But I thought people are working with `KVM` may have work exposure with `VMDK` so just included. If anything is wrong I don't mind removing this tag!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend start with http://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/Creation-of-virtual-machines-utilizing-command-line-tools

But what you should pay attention VMDK file is DISK Image. 
What you need : CPUs, RAM, NIC located in VMX file. It is text file you can edit it manually.

Comment: I do have only `.vmdk` i do not have `.vmx` files, is there any way to create `.vmx` from `.vmdk` files?

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://techhead.co/vmware-esx-how-to-easily-recreate-a-missing-or-corrupt-vmx-file/

Comment: or this http://serverfault.com/questions/579866/deploying-vm-from-vmdk-vmx-file